# How to correctly use "Exists"?

Tags: c#, validation, email

what am i doing wrong? This is an API call where i'm going to save a new user. Basically during the registration of a new user i want to show an Exception and block the save process whenever i insert a mail that is already present in the db.
The problem is that i see the excepetion but the user is saved in my SQL db with the same mail already in there so i have two different Users with the same mail, which is not good.

For example, I have a user with the mail "user@mail.com" already in the db, so when i register a new user and i try to insert "user@mail.com" in the form, when i click on the Save button it should prevent me from saving the user in the db because there is a duplicated mail. Now, the error message appears but the user is saved anyway

```cs
public override int Save(User entity, bool saveChanges = true, bool IgnoreValidation = false, bool checkConcurrency = true)
{
    try
    {
        bool sendMail = (entity.ID == 0);
        string clearPassword = null;
        if (entity.ID == 0)
        {
            // creo una password casuale se non mi arriva nel Json
            clearPassword = string.IsNullOrEmpty(entity.Password) ? _passwordService.MakePassword() : entity.Password;
            // eseguo l'encrypt della password
            entity.Password = _passwordService.EncryptSHA256(clearPassword);
        }

        if (entity.Role == Role.USER)
        {
            if (Exists(x => x.Email == entity.Email && x.ID != entity.ID)) {
                throw new EntityValidationException("E' già presente un utente registrato nel sistema con questa mail");
            }
        }
        int userSavedID = base.Save(entity, saveChanges);

        if (sendMail == true)
            _emailService.CreateNewCredentialEmail(entity, clearPassword);

        return userSavedID;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is `Exists`? Is it a method you wrote? If so, is it actually doing what it's supposed to? If not, what method is it actually?

Comment: Have you debugged the code? You say that the error message is displayed so that seems to suggest that it is hitting the `throw new EntityValidationException`. If that's so then it can't be hitting the `base.Save` line too, so how exactly is the record being saved?

Comment: Throwing an exception doesn't seem to be the right approach here anyway. What's exceptional about someone entering a value that already exists? You should simply be validating the data with an `if` statement.

Comment: Note: instead of 2 nested if-statements you can use only one and combine the two conditions with `&&`. It performs a short-circuit evaluation. I.e., if the first condition evaluates to `false`, the second will not be evaluates (exactly as with the nested if-statements). `if (entity.Role == Role.USER) && Exists(...)) { ... }`

Comment: Never use `throw ex`. That will truncate the stack trace of the exception. If you need to catch and rethrow, just use `throw`.

Comment: thank you all for your efforts, i found out that it was nothing but a matter of code position, using that condition above all the others solved the problem. Thank you so much for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas to check:

1. Is your entity ID working properly? You don't give any details on that, but your duplicate check is excluding where `x.ID != entity.ID`. If the entity ID is wrong and always 0, then the `Exists()` check will always return false.
2. Is your `entity.Role` correctly set to `USER`? If the `entity.Role` is something else (or maybe null) then the check will never happen. It's a bit dangerous because if the `entity.Role` isn't set right then your uniqueness check never happens.

For added protection you should also add a constraint into your database so that the user field needs to be unique. Here is an [example for MS SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-unique-constraints?view=sql-server-ver16) but all similar databases will have this feature. This is for many reasons:

- If you have bugs in the system then it will prevent bad data getting into the database.
- Even if you fix the problem with your current code, there's still the chance of a race condition. For example, if two users try to save the same username at the same time.

Answer (score -2):

I think you forgot to do return 0; after you check if the user is present in the database. Because of that you return "userSavedID" regardless if user email is present in the db or not.

```
hereif (entity.Role == Role.USER)
    {
        if (Exists(x => x.Email == entity.Email && x.ID != entity.ID)) {
            throw new EntityValidationException("E' già presente un utente registrato nel sistema con questa mail");
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `return 0;` is unreachable and will never be executed.

Comment: didn't you say that the error message appears but the user is saved anyway?